# If the series $a_n$ converges but the series of $n|a_n|$ diverges, show that the radius of convergence of the power series $a_nz^n$ equal to one

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have this exercise as homework and I'm out of ideas by now. I have tried to show it by making the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ equal to Taylor series of a function and checking the radius with the criteria $|a_n|/|a_n+1|$ and $|a_n|^{1/n}$ and going from there but I got nowhere.
Do you know of other way to approach it?

Comment: Yet another victim of the pedagogical fallacy which pushes forward the formula involving $\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}$ as the key to understand the notion of radius of convergence (it is not), or even as its definition (the horror...). If only I received 1 peseta each time a question is posted here, where the OP tries desperately to compute a radius of convergence using the $\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}$ stuff, while understanding what the notion really means would immediately yield them the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum_n a_n<\infty$, then from the ratio test

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le 1$$

If $\sum_n na_n$ diverges, then from the ratio test

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}}{n\,a_n}\right|=\liminf_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\ge 1$$

Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1$.

Hence, the series $\sum_n a_nz^n$ converges when

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{a_nz^n}\right|=|z|<1$

and diverges for $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ converges, it is bounded and $\sum a_nz^n$ converges for $|z|<1$.
The radius of convergence is therefore $r\ge1$. If $r>1$, then the
sequence $|a_n|$ decays exponentially...